# How to mock arbitrary url on my computer?

Tags: web, mocking, frontend, interceptor

How i can mock ANY url on my local computer? For example for anywebsite.com/resources/main.js it will return MY predefined response.

So i will go in Google Chrome or any other browser and it that url will be mocked everywhere.

Comment: You're trying to describe a _proxy_.

Comment: try to search 'mock' for a chrome plugin such as [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mokku-mock-api-calls-seam/llflfcikklhgamfmnjkgpdadpmdplmji) , and [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tweak-mock-api-calls/feahianecghpnipmhphmfgmpdodhcapi) , etc

Comment: @KenChan unfortunately these plugins works only on current page. I need global mock for all programs on my computer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool: https://mockoon.com
It allows you to create mock responses to return.

And maybe you can find an answer for what you trying to do at this page: https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/proxy-mode/